# Get pandas.read_csv to treat missing values differently depending on column type

Tags: pandas, csv, nan

I want to read in a csv file and treat blanks in numeric-like columns as nan values and blanks in string-like columns as empty strings. Preferably I would like to not know anything about the columns in advance.

Input `test.csv`:

```
StrCol,FloatCol
a,1.0
b,1.1
,1.2
d,
e,1.3
```

Desired output DataFrame:

```
  StrCol  FloatCol
0      a       1.0
1      b       1.1
2              1.2
3      d       NaN
4      e       1.3
```

Code I've found works in this case is

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
sc = [c for c, dt in df.dtypes.items() if dt == object]
df.loc[:, sc] = df.loc[:, sc].fillna('')
```

I just wondered if there was a more elegant solution. Only putting NaNs in numeric like columns feels like the intuitive way to read the csv for me, so I wondered if there's a read_csv argument that can give this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Not if you want to benefit from the automatic detection of the dtypes.

If you had NaN (or whichever string) in the numeric columns you could use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', keep_default_na=False, na_values=['NaN'])
```

But here, the empty strings are important to automatically define the numeric columns.

In your case this would incorrectly set everything as object:

```
  StrCol FloatCol
0      a      1.0
1      b      1.1
2             1.2
3      d         
4      e      1.3

df.dtypes

StrCol      object
FloatCol    object
dtype: object
```

An alternative to your approach (still the same logic):

```
out = (pd.read_csv(data)
         .pipe(lambda d: d.combine_first(d.select_dtypes(exclude='number')
                                          .fillna(''))[d.columns])
      )
```

Output:

```
  StrCol  FloatCol
0      a       1.0
1      b       1.1
2              1.2
3      d       NaN
4      e       1.3

df.dtypes

StrCol       object
FloatCol    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the more precise code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", keep_default_na=False, na_values={'FloatCol': ''})
```

Comment: This means you need to have prior knowledge of the dtypes of the columns, this won't enable to automatically infer them